# Calculating the sum of the values in a dictionary that exist in a generic list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, dictionary

I'm not especially proficient with LINQ, so I could use a bit of help with this particular scenario.

I have a list of dictionary items. I need to sum the values in the dictionary where the key exists in the list of strings.

How would I write a LINQ expression for something like this?

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> cars = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

cars.Add("Ford", 1.2M);
cars.Add("Chevy", 2M);
cars.Add("Toyota", 3M);
cars.Add("Audi", 5M);

List<string> selectedList = new List<string>();
selectedList.Add("Chevy");
selectedList.Add("Audi");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just so:

```
var sum = selectedList.Sum(s=>cars[s]);
```

Or if you are not sure, that all values are in the dictionary (thanks Tim Schmelter for correction):

```
var sum = selectedList.Sum(s=>cars.ContainsKey(s)?cars[s]:0);
```

**EDIT:**  Even better is from Tim proposed solution:

```
selectedList.Where(cars.ContainsKey).Sum(s => cars[s])
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter  i have updated answer, you are right it was not very safe.

Comment: Thanks. Or you could use: `selectedList.Where(cars.ContainsKey).Sum(s => cars[s])`

Comment: This would be even better if it used `TryGetValue`

Answer (score 5):

You could filter the items from the dictionary and then sum the values:

```
var sum = cars
    .Where(item => selectedList.Contains(item.Key))
    .Sum(item => item.Value);
```

Comment: I'd prefer Maksim's approach. Consider that the dictionary contains thousands of cars but only 1-2 are selected, you always enumerate the whole dictionary and don't benefit from it's lookup performance.

Comment: This will be more efficient than trying to run ContainsKey for each selectedList item

Comment: Interesting point Tim, but what if the List also contains many entries (and perhaps duplicate entries)?  Running `ContainsKey` repeatedly to do another lookup may become challenging...  I'd probably go for `TryGetValue` and not use the extensions in that case I guess.

Comment: @DanField: dictionary lookup is O(1) whereas list needs O(n), so you should always use the dictionary for lookups. All the more if the selected-list suggests that it only contains a subset. Also, don't micro-optimize with avoiding `ContainsKey`. It makes the code more readable. `TryGetValue` needs to use a local variable(if not C#7) for the out-variable which should be avoided in LINQ(side-effects).

Comment: Fair enough @TimSchmelter, although I think it's possible to use that local variable within LINQ just fine - for collections of the suggested size this is a micro-optimization, but if you're dealing with larger collections or if your Dictionary is being accessed concurrently (or is a `ConcurrentDictionary`), I think my solution posted below will work a bit better...  FWIW, I upvoted both the top answers, as they're both viable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

So here's a different approach that might perform a bit better for some edge cases:

```
var sum = selectedList
            .Distinct()
            .Sum(s =>
            {
                decimal d;
                if (cars.TryGetValue(s, out d))
                {
                    return d;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        );
```

You only want distinct values from the list iterated, and this way you'll avoid duplicating lookups in the `cars` dictionary (if that's not the case, then just comment out the `Distinct()`).  This should offer a good balance of performance regardless of whether the list or the dictionary are larger.

Comment: Updated  my explanation - `.Distinct()` can be commented out if it's not the desired behavior.

Comment: With C#7 you don't need such pseudo-linq, then you can use `selectedList.Sum(c => cars.TryGetValue(c, out price) ? price : 0)`, so you don't need to declare out-variables.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative non LINQ answer:

```
decimal total = 0;
foreach (var car in selectedList)
{
    total += cars[car];
}
```

Comment: Even though this is an alternate solution, LINQ provides a cleaner and more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree LINQ is usually more elegant just wanted to provide a different answer

Comment: It's not safe, you'll get a `KeyNotFoundException` with a car in the list which is not in the dictonary